# PLS-00123: program too large (Diana nodes) while trying to compile a package

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, compilation, package

While compiling a package, I ran into an error message:

```
Error: PLS-00123: program too large (Diana nodes)
Line: 1
```

The package in question has about 1k lines (spec) + 13k lines in body. While researching on this, I came across [this Ask Tom question](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:571023051648)

> When compiling a PL/SQL unit, the
>   compiler builds a parse tree.  The 
>   maximum size of a  PL/SQL unit is
>   determined by the size of the parse
>   tree.  A maximum number of diana nodes
>   exists in this tree.
>
> Up to 7.3, you could have `2**14` (16K)
>   diana nodes, and from 8.0 to 8.1.3,
>   `2**15` (32K)  diana nodes were allowed.
>   With 8.1.3, this limit has been
>   relaxed so that you can now  have
>   `2**26` (i.e., 64M) diana nodes in this
>   tree for package and type bodies.
>
> While there is no easy way to
>   translate the limits in terms of lines
>   of source code, it  has been our
>   observation that there have been
>   approximately 5 to 10 nodes per line
>   of  source code.  Prior to 8.1.3, the
>   compiler could cleanly compile up to
>   about 3,000 lines  of code.
>   Starting with 8.1.3, the limit was
>   relaxed for package bodies and type
>   bodies which can  now have
>   approximately up to about 6,000,000
>   lines of code.
>
> This is a rough estimate.  If your
>   code has many spaces, long
>   identifiers, etc., you may  end up
>   with source code larger than this.

Now even if you take into consideration the last list about many spaces & large identifiers, I think it's reasonable to conclude that it's no where close the limits referred above.

Further more,

> How to Check the Current Size of a package:
>
> To check the size of a package, the
>   closest related number you can use is
>   PARSED_SIZE in  the data dictionary
>   view USER_OBJECT_SIZE.  This value
>   provides the size of the DIANA in 
>   bytes as stored in the `SYS.IDL_xxx$`
>   tables and is NOT the size in the
>   shared pool.
>
> [...]
>
> For example, you may begin
>   experiencing problems with a 64K limit
>   when the `PARSED_SIZE` in 
>   `USER_OBJECT_SIZE` is no more than 50K.

Querying this view gives a result of `48929` - so I assume it's fair to size is 47k ?

The weird part is, fetching the same object from another schema and running it in the area I'm having problem results in successful compilation.

So why is this particular area causing problem ?

Comment: I know it is a long shot, but in face of the problem, I need to ask: are your lines very, very large?

Comment: They are, by no means very, very large

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the program you compile your code with add debug information? Apparently it makes difference illustrated on [this forum post](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/598042/pls-00123-program-too-large).

> The issue when doing a compile for
> debug is the extra code that is added
> in for the debugging.
>
> You can try these queries to see:
>
> ```
> ALTER PACKAGE debug COMPILE;
> SELECT type, source_size, parsed_size, code_size
> FROM user_object_size
> WHERE name = 'DEBUG';
>
> ALTER PACKAGE debug COMPILE DEBUG;
> SELECT type, source_size, parsed_size, code_size
> FROM user_object_size
> WHERE name = 'DEBUG';
> ```
>
> Observe the differences in the
> code_size when you compile for debug.

If you're compiling with DEBUG, try to compile in normal so that it does not generate extra code which can generate your error.