# Oracle 11g PL/SQL Diana Nodes Limit

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a statement such as below but its padded out to do 1000 calls at a time. Anything over that throws a PLS-123 error Program Too Large Diana Nodes

```
begin
sp_myprocedure(....)
sp_myprocedure(....)
sp_myprocedure(....)
sp_myprocedure(....)
end
```

We are moving to 11g and I was wondering if this limitation could be increased to 2000 for example.

Thanks

Comment: > "I have a statement such as below but its padded out to do 1000 calls
> at a time" Why would you do that? Why not use a LOOP instead?

Comment: The parameters are different for each stored procedure call

Comment: [Are you compiling with debug information added?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956670/pls-00123-program-too-large-diana-nodes-while-trying-to-compile-a-package)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "I have a statement such as below but its padded out to do 1000 calls
>    at a time"

This is a very bad programming strategy.   Writing the same thing multiple times is a code smell.  Anytime we find ourselves programming with cut'n'paste and then a bit of editing is a time when we should stop and ask ourselves, 'hmmm is there a better way to do this?'

> "The parameters are different for each stored procedure call"

Yes, but the parameters have to come from somewhere.  Presumably at the moment you are hard-coding them one thousand times.  Yuck.

A better solution would be to store them in a table.  Then you could write a simple loop.  Like this:

```
for prec in ( select p1, p2 from my_parameters
              order by id -- if ordering is important 
            )
loop
    sp_myprocedure(prec.p1, prec.p2);
end loop;
```

Because you are storing the parameters in a table you can have as many calls to that proc as you like, and you are not bound by the Diana node limit.

True you will have to move your parameter values to a table, but it is not harder to maintain data in a table than it is to maintain hardcoded values in source code.

Comment: +1 @APC.  It is CRUCIAL to maintain data in a table rather than as values in source code!

Answer (score 1):

If you're just moving from 10g then I don't believe the limit has changed. So, if you're having problems now then you'll have them again in 11g. Take a look at [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:571023051648) Ask Tom article. A general suggestion is to put your procedure in a package. Or, break it down into smaller blocks. If you're only getting the error when running the block which calls the procedure 1000 times and in the procedure on its own then I suggest you try as APC says and loop through it instead as this should reduce the number of nodes.